# Copy worksheet from another workbook opened in the background

Tags: excel, vba

After using Excel VBA code in a macro to successfully download a Google Drive file "myUnits_template.xls" and placing it into the same folder of the active workbook "test_Units.xls", the below VBA code is executed in that same macro to copy Worksheet "myUnits" from the downloaded file and place it after the worksheet defined by Variable "maSheet":

```
Dim wbTarget   As Workbook          ' workbook target to copy a worksheet to.
Dim wbSource   As Workbook          ' workbook source for copying a worksheet from.
Dim filePath   As String            ' file pathname to the downloaded file.
Dim maSheet    As String            ' worksheet name in the currently-active workbook.

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wbTarget = ActiveWorkbook                         ' currently-visible Excel file "test_Units".
filePath = wbTarget.Path & "\myUnits_template.xls"

Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(filePath)               ' open "template" workbook in background.
wbSource.Sheets("myUnits").Copy After:=wbTarget.Sheets(maSheet)
wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False

Worksheets(maSheet).Activate                          ' active worksheet for "maSheet".
```

When the VBA macro executes, the "Workbooks.Open(filePath)" successfully opens file "myUnits_template.xls".  However, it is immediately displayed as the visible workbook with its only worksheet "myUnits" visible and then execution stops; that is, the last three statements in the above code are not executed.  Since this code is to run in the background, the "maSheet" worksheet should be visible with the "myUnits" to the right of it.  For some reason this does not happen, and I have not been able to figure out why this happens.

If a breakpoint is placed on the "Application.ScreenUpdating = False" statement, the macro executes to that point and the Debugger displays the code.  After issuing the Debugger "run/contiue" command, the code properly executes and the "maSheet" worksheet is visible with the "myUnits" worksheet on its right.

If the above code is placed as a new macro of a newly-created workbook containing four worksheets named "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", and "Sheet4", the execution of that macro works properly with "myUnits" appearing to the right of the "Sheet2" worksheet, where "maSheet" is defined to be "Sheet2".

Comment: Welcome Michael! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? Are both workbooks from the same version of Excel?

Comment: I'm using Excel 15.0 and VBA 7.1; both files were created with the same Excel.

Comment: I deleted the answer because it provided wrong information. Something that I noticed now is that `maSheet` is a variable. What is `maSheet`'s value? You don't specify it in this piece of code. If `maSheet` is the exact sheet's name then it needs to be inside quotation marks. `Sheets("maSheet")`

Comment: Variable maSheet is defined in early code of the macro.

Comment: After more investigation on the internet, I found that replacing "Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(filePath)" with "Set wbSource = Workbooks.Add(filePath)" works.